# gSOAP Webservice, Error while compiling

Tags: c++, gsoap

Im using Netbeans IDE 6.9 with G++ Compilingtools on Ubuntu 10.10. If i try to compile my webservice i get the following errors:

```
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/stonService/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `stonSoapBindingService::stonSoapBindingService()'
/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/stonService/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `stonSoapBindingService::serve()'
/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/stonService/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `stonSoapBindingService::run(int)'
/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/stonService/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `stonSoapBindingService::soap_stream_fault(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/stonService/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `stonSoapBindingService::~stonSoapBindingService()'
/home/mark/NetBeansProjects/stonService/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `stonSoapBindingService::~stonSoapBindingService()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/stonservice] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Fehler 2
```

In my main.cpp i included the .h file where are those functions are located. Where is my error? The makefile is generated by netbeans!

Comment: It is an linker error,Are you linking to the gSOAP library? Is it present at the path specified in makefile?

Comment: No, the makefile was generated by Netbeans, how to at the gsoap library?

Comment: Check the documentation of NetBeans to see how to add a Library through settings by searching on google.I don't use netBeans so I cannot say the steps.

Comment: I tried it with a created makefile. I have the stdsoap2.cpp files with it but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to my problem, it was because i didnt had all functions in the wsdl file in my main.cpp!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the files gSoap created to your netbeans project (use the add existing files).

Then, in the project proprieties, you have to:

- use WITH_PURE_VIRTUAL in the preprocessor definitions (this is optional);
- add -lgsoap++ in the libraries to link with;

That should do it. At least, it worked for me.